# Help with list output

Tags: php, list, file-get-contents, explode

I have this expression here

```
$data = file_get_contents('groups.txt');
function links1($l1, $l2){echo "<a href='". $l1 ."'><img src='". $l2 ."'/></a>";}
$parsed1 = get_string_between($data, "[Group1]", "[/Group1]"); 
$data = explode("\n", $parsed1);
foreach($data as $string2){
    list($l1, $l2) = explode(' ', $string2);
    links1($l1, $l2);}}
```

I have a get_string_between defined as a function above that gets anything between "[Group1]" and "[/Group1]". 
The text file groups contains stuff:

```
[Group1]
aaa 1.png
bbb 2.jpg
[/Group1]
```

The problem is that when I run this it outputs as

```
<a href=''><img src=''/></a><a href='aaa'><img src='1.png'/></a><a href='bbb'><img src='2.jpg'/></a><a href=''><img src=''/></a>
```

so I get these dummy two spaces i guess that are added to the front and back of anything thats between

```
aaa 1.png bbb 2.jpg
```

How can I fix that?
Basicly gow can i remove the `<a href=''><img src=''/>` from start and back from the output?

Thanks!

edit: added the get_string_between function

```
function get_string_between(){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
```

Comment: Maybe your `get_string_between` is not functioning how you think it is functioning? Can you post that function?

Comment: I've added the `get_string_between` function as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your `get_string_between` function. I've tried to clean it up here:

```
function get_string_between($text, $start, $end) {
    $n1 = strpos($text, $start);
    if ($n1 === false) return '';
    $n1 += strlen($start);
    $n2 = strpos($text, $end, $n1);
    if ($n2 === false) return substr($text, $n1);
    return substr($text, $n1, $n2 - $n1);
}
```

Hopefully this will help/lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Haha thanks for this! I fixed my problem by modifying last line like `return substr($text, ($n1+1), ($n2 - $n1-2));`